# how to add multiview in a radio button

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist, multiview

```
<asp:MultiView ID="MultiView1" runat="server">
    <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server">
      </asp:View>
 <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server" >
 <table class="style1" style="border: medium groove #808080">
 ......contents.....
</asp:view>


protected void ddlto_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
protected void RadioButton1_CheckedChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
}
protected void RadioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 2;
}

<asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                            RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" 
                                            onselectedindexchanged="MultiView1_ActiveViewChanged">
                                            <asp:ListItem Selected="True">One Way</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>Round Trip</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>Multi City</asp:ListItem>


                                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

> i have a radiolist of thre buttons-one way,round trip and multicity, i have taken a multiview in which in view 2 i have added the codes codes,and i want to show that code when i click on the 2nd radio button i.e on round trip,how to do it. plzz help

Comment: You need to add more code to your question as just looking at that sample, it would work fine.

Comment: @dgarbacz: i have added the codes..pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that from the code you've added you want the *Round Trip* item to be the one that changes the view of your multiview. The way you have the event handler set up on your RadioButtonList is wrong. You can't handle a `ActiveViewChanged` handler on a `MultiView` with a radio button list.

The best thing is to add more to your radio button list like so

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="lstTrip" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small" onselectedindexchanged="lstTrip_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="OneWay">One Way</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="RoundTrip">Round Trip</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="MultiCity">Multi City</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

Then just handle the event on the SelectedIndexChanged like you did

```
protected void lstTrip_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (lstTrip.SelectedValue.ToLower() == "roundtrip")
    {
        //Change the selected multiview index 
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
    } 
    else 
    {
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

You really need to consider naming your controls more descriptively as if anyone else were to look at your code, they would have a hard time understanding it and potentially maintaining it.

Comment: :thanks for ur help, its working but its not taking the value of view2.i have added the code.plz help

Comment: Updated my code. I thought you had 3 views in your MultiView. If you want the second view, the index needs to be 1. Please mark my answer as correct if it is a solution for you :)

Comment: well i have two views view1 and view2 as i have mentioned in the above code. i took on radio button list as you have suggested and i have given the same .cs code as u have given.still i am not able to get the contents of my two views.

Comment: its working fine now now i just want to know what changes i have to do in  my .cs file if i have 3 views..plzz help

Comment: Just reference the view index like you've done already with `ActiveViewIndex`